# How to find grid in picture or array [python]

Tags: python, opencv

I'm stuck at my approach to find the grid in the following picture:
[image: 8-Bit Picture of the grid]

I have either a 8-Bit png file or a 2d-array of its intensities to work with.
I tried to find the grid via a local minima algorithm, but because of the intensity gradient and the noise it didn't quite work well. Also, I tried using OpenCV but I'm not very familiar with it, and it only found the two bald lines and some weird non-perpendicular diagonal lines.

My question would be, if there is a way/algorithm/library to find such fine lines, so that I can define their distance from each other. Thanks. (If more Info is needed I sure can give some, i just didn't wanted to overload this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convolve your image with a filter (matrix). Some matrix produces the result you are looking for( Prewitt filter, Sobel filter or Canny). Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection
After performing a convolution it will be easy to tack the local maximum or minimum.

Also look at CNN (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) which could do the job ^^

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely look it up!

Answer (score 0):

Usually canny edge detection and afterwards hough transformation is a good way to find straight lines in pictures.

```
image = np.array(Image.open('picture.jpg'), dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edged = cv2.Canny(im, xx, yy)
        
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edged,1,np.pi/180,threshold=pp)
```

Comment: That is the way I approached it with OpenCV as well, but it didn't work, no matter how I manipulated the thresholds.